# How to get a specific route data by route name in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

In VueJs i can always access the current route data. but what if i want to access a different route's data by its name ?
suppose i have routes defined,

```
[
    {
        name: "dashboard",
        path: "/",
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: {
            title: "Dashboard",
        }
    },
    {
        name: "login",
        path: "/login",
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            title: "Login",
        }
    }
]
```

now suppose i am in dashboard route. i can access its data by `this.$route` but what if i want to access the meta data of route named as login ?
is there any function which will return me the object of route named `login` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [resolve](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-resolve) method to translate route name into a path like this:

```
const { href } = this.$router.resolve({
  name: 'password-change',
});
```

or if you want more information:

```
const { route } = this.$router.resolve({
  name: 'password-change',
});
```

in return you get an object containing route path, meta, params etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could access the route using this.$router

```
this.$router.options.routes[0].meta
```

Of course you have to grab the correct route

---

**UPDATE**

Of course you could iterate over your array:

```
getRoute: function (routeName) {
  let result = this.$router.options.routes.find(i => i.name === routeName)
  if (result == null) {
    this.$router.options.routes.forEach(element => {
      if (element.children) {
        let route = element.children.find(i => i.name === routeName)
        if (route != null) {
          result = route
        }
      }
    })
  }
  return result
},
```

Comment: i dont have the index of the route. i have the name of the route. and there could be child routes as well.

Comment: The `.find(i => i.name === routeName)` did it for me (where routeName would be 'Dashboard').  I then appended `.children` to the end of that, because my main navigation is all within there.